# ImageView background with height match_parent doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

There's something that is not working well here.

What I need: fill a part of a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` with a pattern background.

What I have done: If i put defined number (in `DP`) to the `ImageView` height, it works. But it's not what I need, because the `RelativeLayout` has a `wrap_content` height. I need that the pattern fills all the relative, with margins top and bottom of `13dp`. (And `10dp` width).

If I put match parent to the `ImageView` height (What I think it's the right solution), it doesn't work (it only shows a line).

This is what I need:
http://postimg.org/image/csr16zccn/

Here is the code of the `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relative2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relative" 
    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
    android:paddingTop="13dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pattern"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/row_pattern" />  

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="18dp"
    style="@style/p_general" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the `row_pattern.xml`

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can set `layout_alginTop="@+id/title"` and `layout_alginBottom="@+id/title"` attributes to your `ImageView` than your image will fill title's height.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relative2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relative" 
    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
    android:paddingTop="13dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingLeft="18dp"
    style="@style/p_general" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pattern"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alginTop="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alginBottom="@+id/title"
    android:src="@drawable/row_pattern" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, this really works, furthermore, I've had to change android:src="@drawable/row_pattern" to android:background="@drawable/row_pattern"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `match_parent` a child if the parent has `wrap_content`. It doesn't make sense. The child cannot match a parent which doesn't have it's dimensions defined. You can either give the parent a height, or just give your image an height. Or you can alwo `wrap_content` your image (the image view knows how to display your image, but in this case it will display the source's resolution and you probably don't want that).

Comment: Yes, it has sense, if you want your child matching your parent.

Comment: It makes sense that a child wants to match an undefined parent size?

Comment: How would you do that if it's not that way? If the parent has variable height and the child MUST have the same height, I think you have to use @loneCRAB solution, which works fine.

Comment: I also provided @loneCRAB's solution:  you can also use wrap_content for the imageview, but in this case if your resource image is too big than your imageview will appear big, and probably you don;t want that. In your case the resource that you provided for the image view most likely has the desired size